# Change values in data frame in a specific row using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Is it possible to restrict a data frame to a specific row and then change some values in one of the columns?

Let's say I calculate `GROWTH` as `(SIZE_t+1 - SIZE_t)/SIZE_t` and now I can see that there are some strange values for `GROWTH` (e.g. 1000) and the reason is a corrupt value of the corresponding `SIZE` variable. Now I'd like to find and replace the corrupt value of `SIZE`.

If I type:

```
data <- mutate(filter(data, lead(GROWTH)==1000), SIZE = 2600)
```

then only the corrupt row is stored in `data` and the rest of my data frame is lost.

What I'd like to do instead is filter "data" on the left hand side to the corresponding row of the corrupt value and then mutate the incorrect variable (on the right hand side):

```
filter(data, lead(GROWTH)==1000)  <- mutate(filter(data, lead(GROWTH)==1000), SIZE = 2600)
```

but that doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to handle this using dplyr? Many thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Such a replacement is usually done as `data <- data %>% mutate(SIZE = replace(SIZE, GROWTH == 1000, 2600))` in dplyr parlance

Comment: Sometimes I think it's worth breaking out of a `dplyr` chain for something like this - `data$SIZE[data$GROWTH==1000] <- 2600` will cover it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use an `ifelse` statement with `mutate` function. Let's say you have a data frame with some corrupted values in SIZE at row 3 which lead to a large GROWTH value at row 4 and you want to replace the SIZE at row 3, with some value `0.3` here(I chose to be different from yours just to be consistent with my values). The `GROWTH > 1000` condition can be replaced accordingly.

```
data
          SIZE       GROWTH
1  -1.49578498           NA
2  -0.38731784   -0.7410605
3   0.00010000   -1.0002582
4   0.53842217 5383.2216758
5  -0.65813674   -2.2223433
6   0.29830698   -1.4532599
7   0.04712019   -0.8420413
8  -0.07312482   -2.5518788
9   1.64310713  -23.4698959
10  1.44927727   -0.1179654

library(dplyr)
data %>% mutate(SIZE = ifelse(lead(GROWTH > 1000, default = F), 0.3, SIZE))
          SIZE       GROWTH
1  -1.49578498           NA
2  -0.38731784   -0.7410605
3   0.30000000   -1.0002582
4   0.53842217 5383.2216758
5  -0.65813674   -2.2223433
6   0.29830698   -1.4532599
7   0.04712019   -0.8420413
8  -0.07312482   -2.5518788
9   1.64310713  -23.4698959
10  1.44927727   -0.1179654
```

**Data**:

```
structure(list(SIZE = c(-1.49578498093657, -0.387317841955887, 
1e-04, 0.538422167582116, -0.658136741561064, 0.298306980856383, 
0.0471201873908915, -0.0731248216938637, 1.64310713116132, 1.44927727104653
), GROWTH = c(NA, -0.741060482026387, -1.00025818588551, 5383.22167582116, 
-2.22234332311492, -1.45325988053609, -0.842041284935343, -2.55187883883499, 
-23.4698958999199, -0.117965442690154)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("SIZE", 
"GROWTH"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```